# Android: Drawer menu + swipeView

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, navigation-drawer, swipeview

I would like to implement a swipe views into my Sherlock fragments with the drawer menu.
I did it and it seems works fine, owever, there is a minor issue that i can't figure out.

So let's begin with some pices of my code:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    // Declare Variable
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ListView mDrawerList;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    MenuListAdapter mMenuAdapter;
    String[] title;
    String[] subtitle;
    int[] icon;
    Fragment fragment1 = new TestFragment();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);

        // Generate title
        title = new String[] { "Test title" };

        // Generate subtitle
        subtitle = new String[] { "Test subtitle" };

        // Generate icon
        icon = new int[] { R.drawable.action_about };

        // Locate DrawerLayout in drawer_main.xml
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // Locate ListView in drawer_main.xml
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        // Pass results to MenuListAdapter Class
        mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(this, title, subtitle, icon);

        // Set the MenuListAdapter to the ListView
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);

        // Capture button clicks on side menu
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // Enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Locate Position
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1);
            break;
        ft.commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        // Close drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

**TestFragment:**

```
public class TestFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    ViewPager mViewPager;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container, false);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pagerTabStrip);

        testAdapter titleAdapter = new testAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(titleAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

**testAdapter**

```
public class testAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private String titles[] = new String[]{"View1","View2"};
    private Fragment frags[] = new Fragment[titles.length];

public systemAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    frags[0] = new testSwipe1();
    frags[1] = new testSwipe2();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle (int position){
    Log.v("TitleAdapter - getPageTitle=", titles[position]);
    return titles[position];
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Log.v("TitleAdapter - getItem=", String.valueOf(position));
    return frags[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return frags.length;
}
```

**testSwipe1 and testSwipe2 are the same:**

```
public class testSwipe1 extends SherlockFragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,          Bundle savedInstanceState) {        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testswipe_layout, container, false);

        ImageButton testImage = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.test);

        //todo function image

        return rootView; 
}

}
```

Ok, the drawer works fine and if i tap on "test title" it inflate the layout with the swipe and i can see the image in the 2 test swipe views.
Owever, if i open back the drawer and tap again on "test title" i can see the swipe views without the images on my swipe fragment layout. If i put the device in landscape and back to portrait, the image on my swipe fragments come back! open drawer -> tap again on test title -> images disappear.... -> landscaper -> portrait -> image back.

The layouts defined are standard for drawer and swipeviews. inside the swipeviews fragments layout there is only an imageview. So the issue must be in the java part but i can't figure out where.
Any helps?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: TestAdapter should implement FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentsPagerAdapter. The reason is that the method getItem() is called differently. I had the same problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: Try "this"... What "this"?

Comment: I mean try this thing: TestAdapter should implements fragmentstatepageradapter instead of fragmentspageradapter. The reason is that the method getItem() is called differntly. I had the same problem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the code given in [here](https://github.com/piterwilson/Easy-Android-Drawer-Layout).

I just change the `asyDrawerLayout.java` file by implementing `OnGestureListener` interface with it's methods.

In the `onCreate()` I have set the gesture to the current context by adding following line.

`gd = new GestureDetector(this, this);`

Then I have Override the `onTouchEvent()` as follows

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Registering TouchEvent with GestureDetector
    return gd.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Then I have changed the `onFling()` as follows

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    //Defining Sensitivity
    float sensitivity = 30;
    //Swipe Left Check
    if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > sensitivity && mOpen){
        closeDrawer();
        return true;
    }
    //Swipe Right Check
    if(e2.getX() - e1.getX() > sensitivity && !mOpen){
        openDrawer();
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now it is working with Drawer menu + swipeView.

You can download my edited version from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?n1t3d8oo3vw3bnb).